# Control style overridden

Tags: asp.net, css, styles

I have the following ASP.Net code

```
...
<div style="width: 40%; float: left; margin-left: 15px">
    <b>County:</b>
    <asp:ComboBox ID="cboCounty" runat="server" MaxLength="0" 
    AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CssClass="EPSCombo">
    </asp:ComboBox>
    <br />
...
```

**The problem:** This div contains many combobox's and they are not showing as expected, they all have `EPSCombo` class. and when I debug the CSS I find that it is being overridden, here is the output from FireBug

[image]

My `EPSCombo` style is as follows (overriding the default AjaxToolkit CSS)

```
.EPSCombo .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer input
{
    margin: 0;
    border: solid 1px #7F9DB9;
    border-right: 0px none;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 18px;
}
.EPSCombo .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/windows-arrow.gif);
    background-position: top left;
    border: 0px none;
    height: 21px;
    width: 21px;
}
.EPSCombo .ajax__combobox_itemlist
{
    border-color: #7F9DB9;
}
```

And the CSS file containing EPSCombo is the last one included in the Master page.

**Question**: It might had been a while since I did web development, but if I decide the CSS class for a control shouldnt that have the highest priority and should override everything else, correct? If so, then why is my combobox style (**Height, Width, margin, and padding**) is being overridden?? I dont have any other style class that set the height and width for those values shown in Firebug.

**Update** after Loki's answer I thought I should add this, adding `!important` to these attributes would solve the problem, but I want to get to the root cause of this and see where things went wrong.

Comment: as you see overridden styles are in line, in line style have highest priority, so you need to check your code may be you add these styles in line in the code or may be using java script..

Comment: I had that concern but as I said I dont have any other place that assign those specific values, also in my question I only show one combobox, but that `Div` has many more and each one of them has a different value. In my JS I dont usually change the `CSS` for controls. Is there a way that I can search or find out if my control style is being modified by JS?

Comment: @JafarKofahi if you have access to .js files - you may search for class names or element tags and look at what's being done to them

Comment: @Loki thanks for the thought, I just checked all of the JS, and the only element style affected by JS is `a`. So it seems its purely CSS issue

Comment: @JafarKofahi that leaves you with a couple of options: either someone's writing inline styles, or you're recieveing (AJAX suggests) html elements with inline styles built in. This is not an issue created by CSS file for sure

Comment: @Loki I already checked for inline styles for those comboboxes and there isnt any. Could you explain more about AJAX suggests? Couldnt it be an inheritance issues as Eric said in his post below?

Comment: @JafarKofahi Eric is absolutely right about inheritance, it's great stuff to read and to know, but it's irrelevant to the case. At the screenshot we see `element.style`, which implies there is an inline style.

Comment: @Loki could you elaborate more about Ajax Suggests? The width and height are being **calculated** but no clue from where. But part of my problem was related to inheritance!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33807/discussion-between-loki-and-jafar-kofahi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ComboBox may be inheriting it's styling from the `<div>` it is contained in, or from a div higher than that.  Since you have not specified a 'class' or 'ID' attribute for the div that it is contained within, that div may be retrieving style from your CSS file if you have something like:

```
div
{
  height: 21px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 21px;
}
```

To force your ComboBox to take independent styling though you may use the asp `style` attribute like so:

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="cboCounty" runat="server" MaxLength="0" 
AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 21px;width: 21px;">
</asp:ComboBox>
```

That should be the highest priority over any other styling that may be interfering in your application.  Although considered improper programming practice it may help you narrow down the issue.

Cheers, Eric

**EDIT**  I should also mention that your CSS code is interpreted in order from the most specific to least specific tag definitions.  Ex, `div.menu` is more specific than `div`, this may be occurring somewhere else in your style-sheet.

[This](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html) is also a good article to look at describing inheritance.  Hope this helps!

Comment: interesting so the inherited styles would override a given CssClass? I will be reading about inheritance..thanks

Comment: +1 @Eric for pointing out the inheritance..that was half of the problem. The second half I am still trying to figure out. The width and height both are being calculated somewhere and assigned as inline values in the HTML output

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix - add `!important` flags to your stylesheet. They'll have higher priority over everything else, unless there are other flags defining the very same property of the very same element

Comment: yes adding `!important` would solve this problem, but I dont want to have to add it every time it happens. I want to find the reason why it is happening: are my CSS files messed up, is me or anyone in my team doing some styling in JS w/o realizing it,...etc

but thanks